# Getting a JButton from the JPanel of Panel

Tags: java, swing

I am struggling with getting JButton object from JPanel in another JPanel ..

I have 2 different JPanels.
1st JPanel : has GridLayout with 4:1
2nd JPanel : has GridLayout with 1:2

then, I put 2 1st JPanels into 2nd JPanel,
and totally put 8 JButtons into each spaces.

Here's my code.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("" + i));
        }
        mainPanel.add(panel);
    }
    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
```

However, I have a problem to get components of panel which is added into the main panel.
I would be so glad if you can give me some help..

Comment: :You can take a `ArrayList` of `JButton` and in inner for loop instantiate each JButton and add it to ArrayList and `panel`. Later use this ArrayList to get JButton object.

Comment: I am so sorry, but can you show me the code to do that

Comment: [example code](http://pastebin.com/9kA308LW) Basically you don't need to getting a JButton, please clarify why you need them. Just add actionListener to the JButton.

Comment: I need to make a key brick game which removes blocks with pressing key and move other blocks down.

Comment: To make this game, I thought I would know how to get Jbutton object from JPanel..